# how to handle a getIntent() method with java nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have 2 activities in my application, **Activity1** and **Activity2**.When the app launches Acitivity1 is the the one that is called.Clicking on a button in Activity1 should take you to Activity2.

In Acivity2,some data processing is done then i send back data to Activity1 using an intent like this:

```
Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity1.class);
  in.putExtra("data", data);
    startActivity(in);
```

Then getting back to Activity1 i obtain the intent data:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

    String data =(getIntent().getExtras().getString("data"));
```

The problem here is that the first time the app launches it checks for the intent data and it does not exist so i get the nullpointerexception error.how can i make sure it checks for the intent data when Activity2 is the previous class?

Comment: use `startActivityForResult`. you can use `if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)`

Comment: `getIntent().hasExtra("data");` is a better option than `if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)`

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the intent is existing using:

```
getIntent().hasExtra("data");
```

This will return you a boolean.

Also if oyu want to return some datas to the first activity, your should start the second one with `startActivityForResult`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (extras != null) {
    if (extras.containsKey("data")) {
        boolean hasData = extras.getBoolean("data", false);

        // TODO: Do something with the value of "data".
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put a check over it

```
if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null){

    String data =(getIntent().getExtras().getString("data"));

}
```

Comment: what if you are passing data from a third activity to MainActivity with a different key then `getIntent().getExtras()` will it be null?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps

1: from your **activity1's button click** call as follow

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

2: In your **Activity2** set the data which you want to return back to **Activity1** as follow and if you don't want to return back don't set anything.

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
 returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
 setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
 finish();
```

***if you don't want to return data***:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);        
finish();
```

3: now again in your **Activity1** handle the return data as follow

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if (requestCode == 1) {

     if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
         String result=data.getStringExtra("result");          
     }
     if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    
         //Write your code if there's no result
     }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

and if you strictly want to use your own method as in your question try this:

in your Activity1 you obtain the intent data as:
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

```
String data ="default value";
try{
   data =(getIntent().getExtras().getString("data"));
}catch(Exception e){
}
```

}

Comment: For reference see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result

Answer (score 0):

use `ActvityForResult`.
replace these codes.

in ACTVITY1:

put this after `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode ,int resultCode ,Intent data ) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

String name =data.getStringExtra("data");
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    switch(requestCode){
    case 2:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

in ACTIVITY2:

```
Intent intent=new Intent();  
intent.putExtra("data",data);  
setResult(2,intent);  
finish();
```