# Null pointer exception when I pass data from another actitvty

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a activity where you select a number in a spinner(dropdown-list in AndroidStudio) and sends it to a new activity/another class, before it is sent to a server. The array-adapter works fine, but using the *getExtra* Intent in the receiving activity is a lot of trouble for me.
The app crashes and logcat give this message:

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference.
>   MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:76)

Line 76 in MainActivity `String avd_nr= getIntent().getStringExtra("getData");`

This is my code for passing the array value, and the line *Log.i("data",avd);* posts the spinner value(avd) in the logcat.

```
btnAvdeling.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                final String avd = dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString();
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("getData",avd.toString());
                    startActivity(i);
                    Log.i("data",avd);
                }
            }
```

This is my code where I receive data

```
String avd_nr= getIntent().getStringExtra("getData");

private SurveyResponse fillInResponsData(Integer answer) {
    surveyResponse.setAvdeling(avd_nr);
    return surveyResponse;
}
```

Please give some help on what i need to add or change

Comment: Is `String avd_nr= getIntent().getStringExtra("getData");` outside a method? As in, is `avd_nr` a field in the class, rather than a local variable?

Comment: write `String avd_nr= getIntent().getStringExtra("getData");` inside `onCreate()`...

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 or at least `avd_nr = getIntent().getStringExtra(...)`. You can still declare the variable outside the method.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I acces *avd_nr* from *onCreate()* method in my *fillInResponsData* method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to handle a getIntent() method with java nullpointerexception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236245/how-to-handle-a-getintent-method-with-java-nullpointerexception)

Answer (score 0):

in onCreate() Method put the following :

```
 String avd_nr =getIntent.getExtras("getData");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String avd_nr =getIntent.getExtras("getData");
```

Its should be on onCreate() method

Comment: I see, but how can I make *avd_nr* in the onCreate() method available for the fillInResponsData method ?